# Laravel 5.1 dynamic database connection

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I am using [laravel5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) with mongoDb. In my application i have separate database for each user.

When user login i set database as per user DB using `Config::set('Key' : 'Value')`.

when i try to get current database connection using `Config::get('database)` everything worked fine but when i am trying to get data from database then it return default database data.

Comment: If you want to get data from a separate Database and not the default database then write your queries like this.  `$users = DB::connection('myOtherDB')->select(user_id from users);`   Here you can pass the name of the Database to the connection and then write whatever query you want to execute.

Comment: Note: this select query is for MySQL but you can change it to whatever query you want for mongoDB.

Comment: @rashidkhan how can i do that in eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::purge('mongodb-name');` i used this after `Config::set("Key","value")`. 
And its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `connection` property in the model as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Model extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $connection = 'your_connection_name_from_database_config';
}
```

You can also set this value dynamically by calling `$model->setConnection('mongo');`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  for suggestion but already try this and didn't worked for me.